# Building a Xamarin Forms App using MySQL

Tags: mysql, xamarin.forms

I would like to build a mobile version of a household financial planner web app that I built with MVC, C#, MS SQL, and Entity Framework. What I've learned from my research is that I should communicate with the database for this project using API endpoints. I am familiar with setting up a WebAPI with MS SQL, but not MySQL. Also, the little work that I have done in that field was based on only retrieving information from the database. Not adding application users, roles, or any rows to tables. The web application that I'm trying to base this Xamarin application is at http://abacus.travismcdaniel.me

I have been unable to find a guide our tutorial that teaches what I need to know. In fact, most of the guides I've found are so outdated that I can't follow the steps because the things they say to do simply don't exist anymore.

So my question is this: It's there a n up-to-date guide anywhere that can walk me through the basics of setting up a MySQL database to use with the app that I'm building, then walk me through writing stored procedures, seeing up WebAPI endpoints for those stored procedures, and then incorporating all of that into a Xamarin Forms application?

If there isn't one single guide that does this, are there a few (still up-to-date) that I can work through to get the same information? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exposing MySQL database/table using REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771485/exposing-mysql-database-table-using-rest)

Comment: if you already have a functioning web app built using MSSQL, why do you need to use MySQL for the mobile backend?  Why not just add a REST API on top of your existing webapp?

Comment: @Jason I considered that, but I still don't know how to translate all of the work I'm doing with EF and LINQ into a REST API. Also, more importantly, I need to know how to do everything with MySQL because my hosting plan with Godaddy only includes 2 MS SQL databases, both of which are already being used (one by the aforementioned web app), and 20 MySQL databases, so I need to learn how to do everything with MySQL that I already know how to do with MS SQL.

Comment: Bottom line, asking for links to tutorials is off-topic for SO.  You could write an entire book on this topic, so it's probably "too broad" on top of that.  There are MySQL libraries that work with EF, so you should be able to fairly easily replace the underlying db without rewriting everything.

Comment: @Jason I realized that it's probably not "the right kind of question", but I have spent so much time trying to find answers on my own it seemed like it was worth a shot. I know that there are ways to make EF work with MySQL, the problem is that none of those methods seem to work with Xamarin. I appreciate your responses, however, and I will look into how to get a RESTful API working with the database that's already in place, just so I've at least got something to work with.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it "works with Xamarin".  Xamarin is the client.  EF and MySQL and everything else runs on your server.  They are very lightly coupled, and generally only communicate via REST and JSON.  If you're looking for extended guidance, try the Xamarin forums, not SO.

Comment: @Jason I will, thank you.